# Autofac Circular Component Dependency - Generic Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I want to register my services with Autofac but I have a circular dependency which is throwing an error. Basically I will raise some events which will be handled by event handlers. There is a domain event dispatcher which will dispatch these events to the event handlers and this will happen in the SaveChanges method of entity framework. 
The graph is as below:

1. The entity framework dbcontext has a constructor dependency of the
   domain event dispatcher.
2. The domain event dispatcher has a constructor dependency of the event 
   handlers.
3. The event handlers have a constructor dependency of generic repository which 
   has the dbcontext.

Right now I have four event handlers(OrderCreatedEventHandler, OrderStatusChangedEventHandler,OrderDispatchedEventHandler,PaymentReceivedEventHandler) and more will be added. And all these event handlers will send email/sms to recipients which would have been configured by the customer.

Before I added a constructor dependency of the domain event dispatcher to the dbcontext my solution was working fine. My implementation is as follows:
Generic Repository Interface:

```
public interface IAsyncRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    // Removed for brevity        
}
```

Generic Repository Implementation:

```
public class EfRepository<T> : IAsyncRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    protected readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;

    public EfRepository(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

}
```

IDomainEventDispatcher:

```
public interface IDomainEventDispatcher
{
    void Dispatch<T>(T domainEvent) where T : BaseDomainEvent;
}
```

IDomainEventHandler:

```
public interface IDomainEventHandler
{
    Task HandleAsync<T>(T domainEvent) where T : BaseDomainEvent;

    bool AppliesTo(Type provider);
}
```

DomainEventHandler:

```
public abstract class DomainEventHandler<T> : IDomainEventHandler where T: BaseDomainEvent
{
    public bool AppliesTo(Type handler)
    {
        return typeof(T).Equals(handler);
    }

    public async Task HandleAsync<X>(X domainEvent) where X : BaseDomainEvent
    {
        await HandleAsync((T)(object)domainEvent);
    }

    protected abstract Task HandleAsync(T domainEvent);
}
```

OrderCreatedEventHandler:

```
public class OrderCreatedEventHandler : DomainEventHandler<OrderCreatedEvent>
{
    private readonly IAsyncRepository<EmailTemplate> _emailTemplate;_notificationRecipientRepository;       

    public OrderCreatedEventHandler(IAsyncRepository<EmailTemplate> emailTemplate)
    {
        _notificationRecipientRepository = notificationRecipientRepository;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleAsync(OrderCreatedEvent domainEvent)
    {
        // Implementation removed
    }
}
```

OrderDispatchedEventHandler:

```
public class OrderDispatchedEventHandler : DomainEventHandler<OrderDispatchedEvent>
{
    private readonly IAsyncRepository<NotificationRecipient> _notificationRecipientRepository;

    public OrderDispatchedEventHandler(IAsyncRepository<NotificationRecipient> notificationRecipientRepository)
    {
        _notificationRecipientRepository = notificationRecipientRepository;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleAsync(OrderDispatchedEvent domainEvent)
    {
        // Implementation removed
    }
}
```

DomainEventDispatcher:

```
public class DomainEventDispatcher : IDomainEventDispatcher
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IDomainEventHandler> _eventHandlers;

    public DomainEventDispatcher(IEnumerable<IDomainEventHandler> eventHandlers)
    {
        _eventHandlers = eventHandlers ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(eventHandlers));
    }

    public void Dispatch<T>(T domainEvent) where T : BaseDomainEvent
    {
        IDomainEventHandler eventHandler = GetEventHandler(domainEvent);

        eventHandler.HandleAsync(domainEvent);
    }

    private IDomainEventHandler GetEventHandler<T>(T model) where T : BaseDomainEvent
    {
        IDomainEventHandler handler = _eventHandlers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.AppliesTo(model.GetType()));

        if (handler == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Event handler for {model.GetType().ToString()} not registered.");
        }

        return handler;
    }
}
```

MyDbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IDomainEventDispatcher _domainEventDispatcher;

    public MyDbContext(IDomainEventDispatcher domainEventDispatcher)
        : base("MyDbContextConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        _domainEventDispatcher = domainEventDispatcher;
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        try
        {
           var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync();

           var entitiesWithEvents = ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>()
                                        .Select(e => e.Entity)
                                        .Where(e => e.Events.Any())
                                        .ToArray();

            foreach (var entity in entitiesWithEvents)
            {
                var events = entity.Events.ToArray();

                entity.Events.Clear();

                foreach (var domainEvent in events)
                {
                    _domainEventDispatcher.Dispatch(domainEvent);
                }
            }

            return result;

        }

        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            //Removed for brevity
        }

    }

    }

}
```

Autofac registration in Web API:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>()
                    .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfRepository<>))
               .As(typeof(IAsyncRepository<>))
               .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<OrderCreatedEventHandler>()
            .As<IDomainEventHandler>();
        builder.RegisterType<OrderDispatchedEventHandler>()
            .As<IDomainEventHandler>();
        builder.RegisterType<OrderStatusChangedEventHandler>()
            .As<IDomainEventHandler>();
        builder.RegisterType<PaymentEventHandler>()
            .As<IDomainEventHandler>();

        builder.RegisterType<DomainEventDispatcher>()
            .As<IDomainEventDispatcher>();
```

Autofac doesn't support circular constructor dependencies as per their docs:

> Two types with circular constructor dependencies are not supported. You will get an exception when you try to resolve types registered in this manner.

How can I enhance my design so that I make Autofac "happy"?

Comment: Any way you can slim this down to remove stuff that isn't needed for the repro? For example, nothing depends on the controller, so that can be removed. It's just that there's a lot to unpack here and keeping it slim will help folks get to the root quicker. Also, when exactly do you see the exception? Is there more to it? Stack trace? Anything else that might help?

Comment: @TravisIllig The error is thrown when the web api application is starting i guess when Autofac is registering the services and their dependdencies. Let me edit the question and remove unnecessary stuff.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that helps troubleshoot these sorts of things is when you boil down the important bits. Like, *really, really* boil it down. You're having problems with circular dependencies, which is all about classes and constructors, so the meat of the thing is:

```cs
public interface IAsyncRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
}

public class EfRepository<T> : IAsyncRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    public EfRepository(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
    }
}

public interface IDomainEventDispatcher
{
}

public interface IDomainEventHandler
{
}

public abstract class DomainEventHandler<T> : IDomainEventHandler where T: BaseDomainEvent
{
}

public class OrderCreatedEventHandler : DomainEventHandler<OrderCreatedEvent>
{
    public OrderCreatedEventHandler(IAsyncRepository<EmailTemplate> emailTemplate)
    {
    }
}

public class OrderDispatchedEventHandler : DomainEventHandler<OrderDispatchedEvent>
{
    public OrderDispatchedEventHandler(IAsyncRepository<NotificationRecipient> notificationRecipientRepository)
    {
    }
}

public class DomainEventDispatcher : IDomainEventDispatcher
{
    public DomainEventDispatcher(IEnumerable<IDomainEventHandler> eventHandlers)
    {
    }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(IDomainEventDispatcher domainEventDispatcher)
    {
    }
}
```

The methods in there, the implementations of the interfaces, etc. aren't really important.

Next thing to do is remove Autofac from the equation. Autofac is basically a fancy way of calling `new SomeClass()` and wiring up dependencies.

**What would you do if you had to make one of these yourself? You can't.**

Let's drop the interfaces and use the concrete class names:

- `EfRepository<T>` needs `MyDbContext`
- `MyDbContext` needs `DomainEventDispatcher`
- `DomainEventDispatcher` needs all of the handlers, BUT
- All of the handlers need `EfRepository<T>`

You couldn't new any of these things up if you tried because there is a circular dependency.

There are several ways to unwind this sort of thing and all require some design

1. **Break things up.** Sometimes classes have dependencies that are only used by one method. Break that into two classes. This adds some separation of responsibility and makes it possible to use the half that *doesn't* cause a circular dependency in the chain. Another thing to think about might be that the event dispatcher could use a different repository or repository type that doesn't cause the circular dependency.
2. **Use method parameters.** For example, what if the event dispatcher took a repository in as a parameter on the various methods that require it rather than having it as a dependency? It may not be as pretty, but it'd break the circle.
3. **Use public settable properties.** Instead of making the repository a constructor parameter on the dispatcher, you could have a public "Repository" property that gets set. You can create the dispatcher then set the property later. No circle during construction.

**The important thing is to think about what you'd do if you had to manually create it.** Autofac can't work around it if it's not something you could manually work around yourself.

[Autofac has docs on circular dependencies](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/circular-dependencies.html) that show how to use property injection to break a circular dependency. [There are also docs on property and method injection](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html) that can help and show examples.